# $\{a,b,c\}$ are $3$ standard normally distributed events. What is the probability that both $a>b$ and $b>c$?

Tags: probability

I think it is a third, but cannot intuitively understand the steps I will take to arrive there.

I figure $P(a>b) = 1/2$, and then we must find $P(b>c|a>b)$. Here I don't see the trick, I thought first we may use:

$P(b>c|a>b) = P(a>b)|b>c) \cdot (P(b>c)/P(a>b))$, but I don't see how this is anything other than a quarter. Thanks.

Comment: It is a normal distribution, so for large b, it is unlikely for a to be even larger. Better to think of this as a combinatorics question.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that they are independent because I think you were implying that. The trick is fairly simple. Note that our random variables are continuous and thus, the probability that some are equal is $0$ and we get
$$P(a>b>c)+P(a>c>b)+P(b>a>c)+P(c>a>b)+P(b>c>a)+P(c>b>a)=1.$$
Since they are also independent, each of these events has the same probability and we get that each of the summands is equal to $1/6$.
The probability you are searching for is $P(a>b>c)=1/6$.
If you would search for the probability that $a>c$ and $b>c$, then you would get $1/3$ since two of the events above satisfy that.

Comment: thanks - someone else had answered giving an answer of an 8th but this looks far better. Think that comment has been deleted now anyways!